# Eigen and parallellization makes no difference for conjugate gradient. Precondition also fails

Tags: multithreading, sparse-matrix, eigen, eigen3

This is related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42116271/best-way-of-solving-sparse-linear-systems-in-c-gpu-possible). I have today experimented a bit with Conjugate Gradient, in particular I experimented with `max_iterations` and `tolerance`. It is faster but not fast enough. According to the documentation it should be enough to add `-fopenmp` in the compilation to enable `multi-threading`.

I have tested using both

```
`omp_set_num_threads(nbrThreads);
 Eigen::setNbThreads(nbrThreads);`
```

It makes no difference in time if I use 5 threads or 1 thread, and that I think is a bit strange.

Secondly, another way to speed up the solution using `pre-conditoning`. When I try to do:

```
    Eigen::ConjugateGradient<Eigen::SparseMatrix<float>, Eigen::Lower, Eigen::IncompleteCholesky<float>> cg;
```

I get the error:

```
    void Eigen::IncompleteCholesky<Scalar, _UpLo, _OrderingType>::_solve_impl(const Rhs&, Dest&) const [with Rhs = Eigen::Matr
ix<float, -1, 1>; Dest = Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, 1>; Scalar = float; int _UpLo = 1; _OrderingType = Eigen::AMDOrdering<int>]: Assertion `m_factorizationIsOk && "factorize() should be called first"' failed.
```

Given that `Eigen::SimplicialLDLT` works which is a Cholesky factorization, then the incomplete should also work?

EDIT:
Here is how I call cg:

```
Eigen::ConjugateGradient<Eigen::SparseMatrix<float>, Eigen::Lower, Eigen::IncompleteCholesky<float>> cg;
cg.setTolerance(0.01);
cg.setMaxIterations(50);
cg.analyzePattern(A_tot);
cg.compute(A_tot);
Eigen::VectorXf opt = cg.solveWithGuess(b_tot, rho_current);
```

Actually when you read about IterativeSolvers [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__IterativeLinearSolvers__Module.html), then `IncompleteCholesky` is not listed. Although IncompleCholesky is defined [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1IncompleteCholesky.html#a409c9586e7d29566dda2c8f5e38a1228).

Comment: Regarding `IncompleteCholesky`, please add the code calling `cg`.

Comment: All calls with cg are added now.

Comment: ILLT probably failed. After the call to compute, check that `cg.preconditioner().info()==Eigen::Success`.  (btw compute is a shortcut for analyzePattern and factorize, so no need to call both analyzePattern and compute). If it returns `NumericalIssue`, then you might try to increase the shift with `cg.preconditioner().setInitialShift(a_small_value_but_large_enough_to_get_it_work)`.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that.

Comment: I tried to change the initialshift, but that did not help. Maybe IncompleteCholesky is not supported?

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the documentation, you need to store the full matrix (both upper and lower triangular part), and pass `Lower|Upper` to `ConjugateGradient` to get multi-threading with cg.

Comment: Thank you, should have seen that myself I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that I had an beta-version of Eigen installed. It runs with pre-conditioner using `Eigen 3.3.2`